# How to redirect in routes.rb for root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing

I have the following at the bottom of my routes file:

```
root :to => 'threads#index', :constraints => lambda {|r| r.env["warden"].authenticate? }
```

The problem with this is the url is just /, not /threads

How can I get the above to redirect to threads#index or /threads ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you just want the default behavior for threads then, in which case you can either add `resources :threads` or `match '/threads' => 'threads#index'` to your Rakefile.
Unless you mean you want the root URL of your site to be `/threads`? In which case you can add `config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/threads'` to your config file.

Comment: @Ankit Soni: why not write an answer (well formatted) instead of a comment?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to change the URL of the root of your site from `http://....com/` to `http://....com/threads`.

In this case, you simply have to add this line:

`config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/threads'`

to any of the standard config files, such as `config/application.rb`, `config/development.rb` or `config/production.rb` depending on whether your app is in production mode or development mode.

There is some more information about this on a rails guide: [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

EDIT:

It seems that the above solution may not work. Here is one I tried myself. You can simply wrap all your pre-existing routes in a scope, inside your `routes.rb` file. i.e:

```
scope "/threads" do
  ..All your preexisting routes inside this..
end
```

Note that this will prepend `/threads` to EVERY path in your app. If you only want this to happen with `root`, then make sure only the `root :to => ...` line is wrapped in the scope.

Here's a simple explanation of scopes: [here](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/)